# What fitness trackers work well for cyclist?

Tags: tracking, heart-rate-monitor

What fitness trackers work well for cyclists? It must also support jogging, walking and other exercise, but cycling is essential.

While there are heaps of 'reviews' of these things, I can't find much that gives me much confidence that any support cycling well.

I have narrowed it to two that explicitly claim to support cycling:

1. the Misfit Shine it has the same accelerometers that most other
   trackers, but it sees to achieve this by asking the user to attach
   it to their ankle.
2. The Withings Pulse Ox - it claims to be able to
   track accurate cycle data with an app called runkeeper

I've also neglected the basis band and peak - I'm interested but the cyclist can't use a band or watch tracker.

Comment: PS there needs to be an 'activity-tracker' tag

Comment: related: [Creating a compendium of fitness and nutrition apps](http://meta.fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/209/creating-a-compendium-of-fitness-and-nutrition-apps)

Answer (score 2):

I personally recommend using the TIMEX RUNKEEPER 1.0 (NOT THE 2.0).

Among other things, this watch allows one to:

1. Select an activity (walking, running, cycling, . . . many others).
2. Monitor and record heart rate using a ANT+ HR monitor.
3. Record GPS data.
4. Display speed, pace, distance, and other related metrics.
5. Easily download data to training peaks.

The Timex Runkeeper 2.0 removed some of the features of the 1.0.

This watch will NOT record Power data from a cycling power meter. For that I recommend the Garmin 500 Edge.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks, good info, but the cyclist can't use a band or watch tracker.

Comment: Is the "TIMEX RUNKEEPER 1.0" a watch, an App, or is it two things together? I can find Timex and I can find Runkeeper, but I haven't found that exact phrase anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

One option is the Garmin Vivosmart. It is a regular activity tracker, that you wear on your wrist, and counts steps when walking or running.

For cycling, it can connect to an ANT+ bicycle speed sensor. So if you have one of these fitted on your bike, the Vivosmart can tell you speed and distance cycled.

See this article from DC Rainmaker, which has some details about using it for cycling: [First look at Garmin’s new Vivosmart activity tracker](http://www.dcrainmaker.com/2014/09/vivosmart-activity-tracker.html)

Comment: Thanks, good info, but the cyclist can't use a band or watch tracker.

Comment: Why can't you use a wristband?

Comment: tiny wrists- like an 8 yo girl - but on grown woman

Comment: Not tried it myself, but apparently the Vivofit or Vivosmart works OK if you put it in your pocket - it still counts steps for walking/cycling. See the comments on that DC Rainmaker article. For cycling, you could strap it onto the handlebars.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using since a year ago the Moov Now Multi-Sport it works pretty well for me.
But there so many things that you need to track depending on your type of cycling and how hard you actually do it, so in my case I'm a beginner on this so for me this tracker works perfect but there some features that are going to be good to have in mind before to buy any tracker like the

Bluetooth / ANT+, Built-in Sensors, Navigation and more for a more detailed version of the features and the different trackers I use [this blog](https://usafitnesstracker.com/fitness-trackers/best-fitness-tracker-cycling/) where I found the moov to be the best for me, I really recommend you to check it out in case you are serious about buying one cause the reality is going to depend on your needs